# Linking multiple files

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

In `bash`, say I want to link some but not all files from a directory, e.g.,

```
ln -s /dir/file1 /dir/file2 ... /other/dir
```

but the format of the names of the files do not follow some simple rule, so we can't use something like

```
ln -s /dir/file* /target/dir.
```

Is there anyway to not repeat `/dir`, something like:

```
/dir/{file1 file2 ...} = /dir/file1 /dir/file2 ...
```

so we can do something like:

```
ln -s /dir/{file1 file2 ...} /target/dir
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the syntax is pretty similar to what you wanted to do.  Saying:

```
ln -s /dir/{file1,file2,foo,bar} /target/dir
```

would link the files `file1`, `file2`, `foo`, `bar` from `/dir/` to `/target/dir/`.

The above syntax is referred to as [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html).

(Brace expansion causes `/dir/{file1,file2,foo,bar}` to expand to `/dir/file1 /dir/file2 /dir/foo /dir/bar`.)

Comment: Thanks! I remember that notation, now that you mention it!!! I saw it somewhere then I forgot, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For complex rules try so:

```
cd dir
find . -name 'file1*' -or -name 'file2*' -or ... -exec ln -s '{}' '/other/dir/{}' ';'
```

Take notice that all '*', '{}' and ';' must be quoted for preventing shell expansion and raw passing to find!

For simple enumerations is shell expansion `{aa,bb,cc}` good enough.